# knockout.js data-bind dropdown list value to array index - is it possible?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

```
function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.addPerson = function () {
    this.PersonIdList.push(0);
  }

  this.showSecondSection = ko.computed(function() {
    // need logic here?
  }, this);

  this.PersonIdList = ko.observableArray();
  this.PeopleChoices = ko.observableArray([
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Person A"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Person B"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "Person C"
    },
  );
}


<!-- ko foreach: PersonIdList -->
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">                
  <select id="idList" data-bind="options: $root.PeopleChoices, optionsValue: 'Id', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: '-- Please Select --', value: ??"></select>                                                             
</div> 
<div data-bind="visible: showSecondSection">Hi</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click: addPerson">Add person</a>
```

I'm wondering if I can databind this chunk to an item in the PersonIdList? 
Also, can I make a second div container inside the loop that's conditionally visible if the Id = 3.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you have an array, you are binding it properly, and it is showing and acting as you want it to, so what is the exact problem?

Comment: When I use the debugging thing <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>, it doesn't show the data-bound value changing inside the array.

Comment: Just make your properties of the array observable.  Then you don't need the indexes or anything like the answer shows.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Thanks! Now, how would I write a showSecondSection method based on the value of the id in the selectlist above it?

Comment: Glad you found your answer, be aware that while that does indeed do the trick using indexes in Knockout observableArrays is not the 'right' way to do it, as you could easily sort the list and then the index doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an observableArray of IDs that you bind to a foreach.  In each of the `<div>`s, you have a select option list (dropdown) that you bind to the PeopleChoices array.  And you want to bind the current iteration of the PersonID to the dropdown list's value?

I'm not sure what your desired result is or why you would want to do this.  It is possible, sort of.  I wasn't sure what would happen when a new option was selected in the dropdown lists.  I guessed nothing would happen and nothing did happen.  Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AG22R/).

All you had to do was set the value binding to `$data` like this:

```
<select id="idList" data-bind="options: $root.PeopleChoices, optionsValue: 'Id', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: '-- Please Select --', value: $data"></select>
```

In each iteration of the personIdList, the $data set the selected value, but once you change the selection, nothing will happen because the observableArray is filled with static data.  So I thought, what if they were observables?  So I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AG22R/1/) and I though it would at least update the value in the observable, but it didn't.

So yeah, you can, but it's weird.  Not sure why you would want to do this.

Update: Could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AG22R/2/).

Comment: Notice, in your fiddle though, that the numbers aren't changing on the page.  I don't think it's data-binding correctly.  But I see they are in the second one!

Comment: So I just tried this out and it's working the way I'd want it to work.  So given that, how would I display that second section using ko.computed if the Id is set to 3 only? Basically I'd need to pass the current array index to the ko.computed, no?

Comment: The answer to the second part was I created an object that I passed into the array instead of a raw value.  Your answer got me there, Dennis.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AG22R/3/) demonstrating the visible part, although it's a 'dirty' fix.  I don't like seeing function calls or comparisons in bindings so I would probably add a dedicated observable that I'd update on a subscription to the 'id' observable property.  This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AG22R/4/) makes more sense to me in this scenario.  Glad you were able to get there from my code example.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4Dv3y/1/

Check out this way Adam.  I think it is a cleaner solution, and you are using observables and also you can use a property like showValue to show the span when you want.  This is more of how you should use observables in Knockout, you don't want to rely on indexes when you are using powerful objects in JavaScript like this.

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedPerson">
The name of the person that is selected is : <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
<h4 data-bind="visible: ShowHighlight">OMG SECOND PERSON IS SHOWN!</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work because when you change any of the single dropdowns, all of the others change as well.

Comment: Obviously you would have to tailor the answer to fit your project, but yes this is the correct way to handle what you are trying to do.  Using indexes is not the right way.